# uialertview don't do action

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I have to put an alert view with the two buttons, but the buttons don't open the urls. I don't know the error. Help please.

Here's the code:

```
-(IBAction)showAlertView {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Obrir en..."
                      message:@"Es pot requirir la aplicació de Google Maps"
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Millor no..."
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Mapes",@"Google Maps",nil];
[alert show];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if([title isEqualToString:@"Mapes"])
{
    UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *ourPath = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=Plaça+del+Rei+43003+Tarragona";
    NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
    [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];

}
if([title isEqualToString:@"Google Maps"])
{
    UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *ourPath = @"comgooglemaps://?daddr=Plaça+del+Rei+43003+Tarragona&directionsmode=walking";
    NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
    [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
}
    }
```

Comment: The second UIALERTVIEW don't open the url

Comment: can you understand me?

Comment: Is this on your simulator or device? If you put a break point inside the Google Maps if, does it stop in there?  I think you should also try canOpenUrl:, as a test, like @rmrahul suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do url encoding for your urlString because it contain some special character.

```
NSString *ourPath = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=Plaça+del+Rei+43003+Tarragona";
ourPath=[ourPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: What is the special character? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

Comment: in this url the special word is Plaça (ç special character)

Answer (score 0):

```
clickedButtonAtIndex...
```

It is delegate method of `UIAlertView`, This method is use for fire action related to selected button of `UIAlertView`

for example :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if(buttonIndex == 1)
  {
      /// write code for button 1 of UIAlertView; (here put 1 URL)
  }
  else if(buttonIndex == 2)
  {
    /// write code for button 2 of UIAlertView; (here put 2 URL)
  }
}
```

So, why you use two UIAlertView for TWO URL, put url in separated block of button clicked in delegate method of `UIAlertView`.

Comment: I have two views and each view i have to put an alert view with the two buttons, but in the second view don't open the url.

Answer (score 0):

I thing your send URL is wrong

it should be

```
maps.google.com//?daddr=Plaça+del+Rei+43003+Tarragona&directionsmode=walking
```

instead

```
comgooglemaps://?daddr=Plaça+del+Rei+43003+Tarragona&directionsmode=walking
```

Comment: i think that's correct, look this:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Comment: then You need to check first [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *enc = [match.location stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=",enc];
NSLog(@"%@", location);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:location]];
```